# extjs - Add images to tagfield combobox and labels

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I need to attach thumbnail (small image) to the labels in the tagfield.

I've found this unanswerd question:
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?330338-Ext-form-field-Tag-HTML-encodes-the-labelTpl

I've found and edited some code in order to show images on the combobox:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jdp

but didn't succeed to make it work in my final code on the Architect.

- In that example i've mentioned, i use 'tpl' to write html template.
  But first, there is no such property in the Architect software (unless you add it as a custom property), 
  and even if i do so, it doesn't work.

thanks

code (not working here, run the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jdp) above):

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'SnirFiddle',// by snir elgabsi

    launch: function() {
        var cities = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['name', 'isTitle'],
            data: [
                { type: 'Animal', petname: 'Human', img:'http://i56.photobucket.com/albums/g181/thejoker1x/th_HomerFalling.gif' },
                { type: 'Animal', petname: 'Lion', img:'http://icons.veryicon.com/ico/Animal/Animal/lion.ico'},
                { type: 'Bird', petname: 'Starling', img:'http://ted-parker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/StarlingTHUMB.jpg' },
                { type: 'Bird', petname: 'Dove', img:'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/outline-signs/350/dove-512.png' },
                { type: 'Fish', petname: 'Nemo', img:'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aquatic-wildlife/135/_nemo-128.png' }
            ]
        });
        
        Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Tag', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose Pet',
            store: cities,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 
            '{[this.currentKey = null]}',
            '<tpl for=".">',
             '<tpl if="this.shouldShowHeader(type)">',
                 '<div class="group-header"><b>{[this.currentKey = values.type]}</b></div>',
                '</tpl>',
                '<img src="{img}" style="float: left; width: 32px;">',
                '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{petname}</div>',
            '</tpl>',
            {               
                shouldShowHeader: function(key){
                    return this.currentKey != key;
                },
                getHeader: function(key){
                    this.currentKey = key;
                    return key;
                }
            })
        });
    }
});
```